# whitespace trimming in the right side of my report issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

i am using sqlplus to generate report,i will spool the output of query in sqlplus screen and making report

now i want a report which having spaces

```
SELECT '123'||lapd(count(1),12,'0')||rpad(' ',10',' ') from dual;
```

i expect the report should spool as  (im showing space as dot(.) to explain you)

```
123000000000009..........
```

but i got

```
123000000000009
```

i have lot of query like this...

i am using

```
set trimspool on    
set termout off    
set linespace 300
```

any idea?

Answer (score 3):

> SET TRIMSPOOL ON removes trailing blanks at the end of each displayed or spooled line.

If that's so, and you want to keep those blanks at the end of the result, why on Earth did you use that setting? Remove it!

Comment: yes i tried removed it but it make file as spaces upto 300 linesspaces..i want space upto i required only for each line

Comment: yes but its not working as expected producing 240 line is wrapped

Comment: If I understood you correctly, enlarge line size, i.e. `set linesize 1000`